# Python. Как воспроизводить input в цикле?

Tags: python, list, циклы

Мне нужно написать программу, которая *В цикле(!)* ожидает последовательного ввода десяти чисел по отдельности, добавляет их в список, сортирует, умножает на 10 и выводит список.

Вот, что у меня получилось:

```
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
d = int(input())
e = int(input())
f = int(input())
g = int(input())
h = int(input())
i = int(input())
m = int(input())
sp = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, m]
for x in sp:
    x = x * 10
    sp.sort()
    print(sp)
```

Пожалуйста, превратите это в правильный код.

UPD: Возможно, я неправильно понял задачу, поправьте, если это так.

Comment: Вы хотите в цикле добавлять в массив новое значение `int(input())`, верно?

Comment: Да, всё правильно

Comment: И... Вы хорошо знаете, как работают [циклы](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/cikly-for-i-while-operatory-break-i-continue-volshebnoe-slovo-else.html) и [массивы](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/spiski-list-funkcii-i-metody-spiskov.html)?

Comment: Нет. Иначе, я бы не обратился сюда. Я только начал изучать эту тему. Судя по вашему вопросу, я что-то делаю не так, верно?

Comment: Что же вам помешало написать код именно так, как написано словами: "В цикле(!) ожидает последовательного ввода десяти чисел по отдельности, добавляет их в список"?

Answer (score 5):

```py
sp = []
for _ in range(10):
    sp.append(int(input()))
for x in sp:
    ...
```

Таким образом мы в цикле заполняем массив.

Answer (score 1):

```
lis = []
for i in range(10):
    num = int(input())
    lis.append(num)
for elem in lis:
    lis[lis.index(elem)] = elem*10
lis.sort()
for elem in lis:
    print(elem)
```